# Xamarin MessagingCenter not working for some pages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

I'm using messagingcenter to send message from a viewmodel to another viewmodel, the destination content page can be accessed from master page only(by clicking on hamburger icon). message can be send successfully to the previous and next pages but cannot send to pages within master page.Please help..

```cs
MessagingCenter.Send<Cart_page_vm>(this, "check_address_id");
```

```cs
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Cart_page_vm>(this, "check_address_id", (sender) =>
{
    //  getaddresses();
});
```

Comment: has the class that is subscribing already been instantiated and subscribed BEFORE the message is sent?

Comment: No. class was not instantiated. That was the issue.Now messege send is  working.. Thank you sir..why  it is necessary to instantiate?